# Weird strange things happening in repository record!

Tags: vb.net, subsonic

SubSonic 2.2. I use the repository record pattern, with a table "appointment" with an appointmentId as auto-incrementing int.

I am trying to update it, but when I do update the fields with something totally different, dirty columns are always zero, and I get an exception.

**System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at SubSonic.DataService.ExecuteQuery(QueryCommand cmd) at SubSonic.SubSonicRepository.Update[T](RepositoryRecord`1 item, String userName) at janji.Janji.Data.DB.Update[T](RepositoryRecord`1 item) in A:\Source\VS2008\Web\Apps\janji\janji\Classes\DAL\AllStructs.vb:line 197 at janji.WebForm4.SaveData() in A:\Source\VS2008\Web\Apps\janji\janji\UI\Appt.aspx.vb:line 343**

Here's my code:

```
        Try
        If Appointment.AppointmentId > 0 Then

            Appointment.AddressName = uxHotel.Text
            Appointment.Address = uxAddress.Text
            Appointment.AppStartTime = Date.Parse(uxApptDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString + " " + uxApptStartTime.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortTimeString)
            Appointment.ApptEndTime = Date.Parse(uxApptDate.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString + " " + uxApptEndTime.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortTimeString)
            Appointment.Completed = uxCOmpleted.Checked
            Appointment.DropNumber = uxDropNum.Text
            Appointment.Total = 0
            Appointment.EmployeeId = 0
            Appointment.Model = uxModel.Text
            Appointment.DropAmount = Decimal.Parse(uxDropAmount.SelectedValue)
            Appointment.RoomNumber = uxRoom.Text

            'If Appointment.DirtyColumns.Count > 0 Then
            Janji.Data.DB.Update(Of Janji.Data.Appointment)(Appointment)
            'End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        _ErrorMessage = ex.ToString
        RetVal = False
        lErrors.Text = _ErrorMessage
        lErrors.Visible = True
    End Try
```

Comment: I can't quite follow what you're doing here. Can you summarize a bit more? Is that an instance or are you using the structs? It looks to me like you're using the structs and not instantiating an object.

Comment: I'm creating it as follows:

_Appointment = New SubSonic.Select().From(Janji.Data.Tables.Appointment). Where(Janji.Data.Appointment.Columns.AppointmentId).IsEqualTo(CallLog.ApptId).ExecuteSingle(Of Janji.Data.Appointment)()

Comment: Also: dirty columns is always 0, even after setting properties.
If I mark as "markClean" the update does NOT fail but does not update anything.

Comment: I found the fix. Add Appointment.MarkOld and .MarkClean before setting properties, then it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the Structs we provide instead of instantiating an Appointment object. Do everything you're doing here, but create an Appointment instance and assign it the values. Then pass that instance to the repo.